# Using regular expression while specifying mapping char filter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

ElasticSearch supports [mapping char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html), where in one can specify a key and its corresponding value. I want to use regular expression in key.

The regular expression I am trying is basically to catch all uppercase symbols ending with `I` and convert them to strings ending with l. So this looks something like

```
ABCI => ABCl
```

String before `I` is not fixed, hence I am writing regular expression.

I have figured out the left hand part of the expression as `[A-Z]+I` but I am not able to decide what should be written on the right hand side so that I can catch string `ABC` as well.

My question is can we use regular expression in mapping char filter. If yes then how can I write the concerned regular expression(especially the right hand side part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Pattern Replace Char Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html):

```
{
"settings": {
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "my_analyzer": {
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "char_filter": [
        "my_char_filter"
      ]
    }
  },
  "char_filter": {
    "my_char_filter": {
     "type": "pattern_replace",
      "pattern": "([A-Z]+)(I)$",   ==> Patterm containg uppaer case characters ending with I
      "replacement": "$11"         =>  Replacing Group 1 with '1'
      }
     }
    }
   }
 }
```

hope this helps!!

Comment: This solution is fine for one key, but I have a case where in I which keys will be updated when ES is running. What about that ? I was looking for something as flexible as `synonyms file`

Comment: That was not what the question mentioned. Question Was about `Regex expression` and the answers addresses that problem. Create another question for that

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the help